# dictionary does not contain a definition for contains

Tags: c#

I have such code

```
Dictionary<string, Object> dollarSignConvertedVals = TryToConvertAllDollarSigns(TryToConvertAllEnvVar(values));
```

When I am trying to find out if there contains a value by key like this

```
if (!dollarSignConvertedVals.Contains(JSON_KEYS.CONNECTION_CONFIG)){}
```

I am getting such weird issue

> Dictionary does not contain a fedination for Contains and the best extension method overload Queryalbe.Contais(IQuerable, string) requeres of type IQueryable

[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: You want `ContainsKey`.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is `ContainsKey`. `Contains` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` that takes a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` to compare with, which -in most cases- is not useful or practical.

In your code, it would be:

```
if (!dollarSignConvertedVals.ContainsKey(JSON_KEYS.CONNECTION_CONFIG)){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have `ContainsKey` and `ContainsValue` methods instead. You want:

```
if (!dollarSignConvertedVals.ContainsKey(JSON_KEYS.CONNECTION_CONFIG)){}
```